# How can I retrieve Org file meta data (filetags) from an (org-element-parse-buffer) tree?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'd like to return a string of comma separated `#+FILETAGS` from an org file that I can use when autogenerating a sitemap for my blog.

I have the impression I can use `(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) ...` (described [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38303/org-element-parse-buffer-usage) but I can't figure out how. I'd like to retrieve the `#+FILETAGS:` metadata.

```lisp
(defun org-publish-find-file-tags (file)
  "Return a string of comma separated file tags for the file at FILE
    
  (let* ((visiting (find-buffer-visiting file))
         (buffer (or visiting (find-file-noselect file)))
         title)
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) ???
        )))
```

### Update

I succeeded using NickD's solution below, but I changed `(string-split value ":" t))))` on the last line of `my/org-get-filetags` to `(split-string value ":"))))`

It looks like this:

```lisp
(defun my/org-get-filetags (e)
  (let ((type (org-element-type e))
        (key (org-element-property :key e))
        (value (org-element-property :value e)))
    (if (and (eq type 'keyword) (equal key "FILETAGS"))
        (split-string value ":"))))

(defun org-publish-find-file-tags (file)
  "Return a string of comma separated file tags for the file at FILE"

  (let* ((visiting (find-buffer-visiting file))
         (buffer (or visiting (find-file-noselect file)))
         title)
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (string-join
       (flatten-tree
        (let ((ret))
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (search-forward "#+FILETAGS:" nil t)
            (save-excursion
              (beginning-of-line)
              (setq ret (cons (my/org-get-filetags (org-element-at-point)) ret))))
          (nreverse (delq nil ret)))) ","))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/org-get-filetags (e)
    (let ((type (org-element-type e))
          (key (org-element-property :key e))
          (value (org-element-property :value e)))
      (if (and (eq type 'keyword) (equal key "FILETAGS"))
          (string-split value ":" t))))

  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) '(keyword) #'my/org-get-filetags)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
((foo bar baz) (tag1 tag2 tag3))
:end:
```

The Org mode file I used for the testing has two `#+FILETAGS:` keywords like this:

```
#+FILETAGS: :foo:bar:baz:
#+FILETAGS: :tag1:tag2:tag3:

...
```

That explains the output of the code block.

This asks `org-element-map` to act on the parse tree of the buffer, selecting only `keyword`s (like `#+FILETAGS`) and applying the function `my/org-get-filetags` on each such element.

The function itself selects the `key` and `value` properties of the element, checks that the type of the element is `keyword` and the key is the string `"FILETAGS"` and, if so, splits the value (a string of the form `":tag1:tag2:tag3:"` on the `:` separator and returns the list of tags (omitting the opening and closing null strings because of the final `t` argument given to `string-split`. See its doc string with `C-h f string-split` for the details.)

`org-element-map` wraps all the return values in a list, so the result is going to be something like `(("foo" "bar" "baz") ("tag1" "tag2" "tag3"))` which you might need to massage some more for your purposes, but I'll leave that to you.

If your file is big, then parsing the whole buffer to get the single keyword you are interested in will be relatively slow. You might be better off if you first search for `#+FILETAGS:`, moving to the beginning of the line and then using `(org-element-at-point)` which does a partial parse around `point`. There would be no need for `org-element-map` then:

```
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (progn
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward "#+FILETAGS:")
      (beginning-of-line)
      (my/org-get-filetags (org-element-at-point))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
(foo bar baz)
:end:
```

Note that we are reusing the same function as in the first code block to get the tags, and that we pass to it explicitly the single element that `org-element-at-point` returns - in the previous case, `org-element-map` would call it repeatedly, implicitly passing each element in the parse tree to it. The final result is a list of tags, rather than a list of lists of tags, since `org-element-map` is not part of this implementation, so there is no wrapping of return values. This assumes there is a single `#+FILETAGS:` keyword in the file, otherwise it will only find the first one (as in this case).

But you could loop searching for all of them:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/org-get-ALL-filetags ()
    (let ((ret))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (search-forward "#+FILETAGS:" nil t)
          (save-excursion
            (beginning-of-line)
            (setq ret (cons (my/org-get-filetags (org-element-at-point)) ret))))
        (nreverse (delq nil ret))))

  (my/org-get-ALL-filetags)

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
((foo bar baz) (tag1 tag2 tag3))
:end:
```

This produces the same list of lists structure as the `org-element-map` implementation, at the cost of complicating the return value of the function a bit: we cons each list to the front, delete any `nil`s (which might be produced when you have the code block as part of the file, because the search succeeds not only for the "real" `#+FILETAGS:` keywords but also for the "fake" instance in the code block itself - the search finds the string in the function, but the parsing of the line does not return a `keyword` type and `my/org-get-filetags` applied to the element at `point` returns `nil` which gets consed to the return value). `cons` adds each list of tags to the front, so we have to reverse the list to produce the "natural" order.